# macOS Sierra Apple Watch Unlock - persistant iCloud Sign in required dialog

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, apple-watch, unlock

I have a **MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)** that I just *reinstalled* macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and now I am trying to use my Watch to unlock.

I had this working before in the past before the reinstallation.  Also, I have it working on another older MacBook Pro. (Post 2013)

I get the following dialog:

> **Your Apple Watch must be signed into iCloud to allow it to unlock your Mac.**
>   You can sign in using the Apple Watch app on your iPhone.

After trying the following steps, I still get the dialog.

- Verified that the Apple Watch is indeed signed in on the proper Apple ID
- Verified that macOS is signed in on the same Apple ID
- Rebooted the Apple Watch and unlocked it ([See this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254396/120171))
- Verified that all components are on the same WiFi network and Bluetooth is enabled

I have not unpaired the watch then paired again.  Hoping not to have to go to that extreme.

*Question: How can I get past the dialog?  What am I missing here?*

> **Hardware:**
>
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) running macOS Sierra 10.12.3
> - iPhone 7 iOS 10.2.1
> - Apple Watch 1st generation watchOS 3.1.3

[image: System Preferences Dialog]
[image: Watch AppleID Settings]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that macOS needed to be rebooted.

To solve the problem:

- Be sure all of the above steps in question have been done
- Reboot MacBook
- Verify the settings in **System Preferences > Security and Privacy**

Now the unlock with Watch is working.

[image: System preferences dialog]

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem: In settings I was definitely logged into iCloud, but the Apple Watch unlock setting still claimed I wasn't.

I stumbled on the following weird solution:

I happened to start `FaceTime` on Mac, and noticed that I wasn't logged into it. I logged in.

When I then opened the Security settings again, the `Allow your Apple Watch to unlock your Mac` was checked!

Comment: Same for me after a Mojave upgrade - thanks! (I also ran the Watch app and visited General->AppleID, but since it was already logged in there was nothing to do there.)

Comment: I was logged in, but logged out and in again to FaceTime and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! How obscure.This did the trick for me and saved me a bit of frustration.

Comment: Good answer. There is no hint from Mac that FaceTime was logged out.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I tried EVERYTHING to fix it.   Saw your note about not being signing into Facetime.   Well, I was signed into both Facetime and Messages, but I thought, what the heck.  Unchecked Enable this Account in Messages setting, then re-enabled it and voila, my Apple Watchs showed back up as options to check to unlock my Mac again.

Comment: Same trick (disable / enable Facetime) worked for me too !!!